# A very interesting Fouriertransform

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\frac{e^{i \omega t}e^{i \omega  R}}{{((\omega-\Omega-iA^2(1+e^{i \omega  R}))((\omega-\Omega-iA^2(1-e^{i \omega  R}))}}
$$

All constants are positve real numbers.

During my work i came across this very interesting integral. 
My plan was to specify the poles of the integrand which are given in terms of Lambert's W-Function, close the integration contour in the appropriate half-plane and use residue theorem to get the result.

The problem now is that we obtain a very nasty sum in the end which i think has to be evaluated numerically. Therefore i wanted to ask the community may have a better idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Please show the work you have already done.

Comment: as i said, ihave a solution in terms of an infinite sum using residue theorem.

Comment: What's wrong here #### downvoter?